# Is there a sense in which $\infty$ is prime? Maybe since $\aleph_0 = \aleph_0*1$?

Tags: set-theory

Some crank on the internet wrote to me that I apparently proved that infinity is prime. This statement is so stupid, it becomes genius again, because if you think about it, in some sense $\aleph_0$ only has the factorisation $\aleph_0*1$. Well, actually there is also $2*\aleph_0$, but you have to use the non-commutativity of ordinals. Maybe there is a canonical way to define factorisation such that this becomes true, say each factor has to be smaller than the previous ones. Is there a general theory on prime ordinals? For example, aren't all limit ordinals prime in the proposed canonical system?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, my knowledge of ordinals is very limited.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Factorization_into_primes

Comment: If $x$, $y$ are cardinals with $x$ infinite, then $x\mid y$ iff $x\le y$. Also using that $xy=\max\{x,y\}$ for infinite cardinals, we can deduce that for $x$ infinite, $x\mid yz$ iff $x\mid y$ or $x\mid z$. That means, every infinite cardinal is a [prime element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) in the Ring of cardinals.

Comment: @ViHdzP Cardinals don't form a ring, since there aren't additive inverses.

Comment: If you're writing $\aleph_0$, you are talking about cardinal arithmetic, not ordinal arithmetic. This is one of the few cases where a symbol has only one meaning and context in modern mathematics.

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number , so no.